# Why does QQmlComponent::create() return nullptr?

Tags: qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

Under what conditions does QQmlComponent::create(QQmlContext *) fail by returning nullptr? The documentation only says " Returns nullptr if creation failed" without further detail. My backend C++ code tries to instantiate a MessageDialog from the following qml:

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
    import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

    MessageDialog {
      id: messageDialog
      title: "My message"
      text: "Fill in this message from C++"
      onAccepted: {
          console.log("Knew you'd see it my way!")
          // Hide the dialog
          visible = false
      }

      Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    }
```

And here's a fragment of my backend constructor:

```
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Note that component resource is local file URL,
    // not network - no need to wait before calling create()?
    QQmlComponent *component = 
      new QQmlComponent(&engine, 
                        QStringLiteral("ui-components/MessageDialog.qml"));

    // Following call returns nullptr
    QObject *childItem = component->create();
```

Anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: When I change the relative path provided to the QQmlComponent constructor to an absolute path, the subsequent call to create() works. I don't know why this is. Also why doesn't the Qt system print out any kind of information when create() fails? Took me hours to track down this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is finding your qml file. Presuming your "ui-components/MessageDialog.qml" is in a qrc file, try:

```
new QQmlComponent(&engine, QStringLiteral("qrc:/ui-components/MessageDialog.qml"));
```